# React, render material ui icon dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, icons

I need some assistance with the following problem. I'm using material ui icons, and the project is set in a way that when I want to use an icon I have to do this:

```
import {Muicon } from '@/lib/material';

 ...

<Muicon.Visibility />
```

With that the eye Icon appears.

Now what I want to do is this: there is an screen where the user could choose the Icon that want to show in other screen, so for example the user writes "Visibility" (just a string) and with that the <Muicon.Visibility /> component has to be showed in the other screen.

The problem is that I can't do something like

```
<Muicon.{userIcon} />
```

Can someone tell me how to do this? I have to create a component with the string that the user enters, there's a way to do this? or I need a different approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a function to return the icon

```
const GenerateIcon = (variation, props = {}) => {
    const IconName = Muicon[variation];
    return <IconName {...props} />;
};
```

and use it

```
<div>
  <p>{GenerateIcon("Visibility")}</p>
  <p>{GenerateIcon("VisibilityOff")}</p>
  <p>{GenerateIcon("AddAPhoto", {color: "secondary"})}</p>
</div>
```

here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-5b1ug?file=/demo.js)

---

If I want a more cleaner way to do this, I'll create a separate component

```
const Icon = ({ name, ...rest }) => {
    const IconComponent = Muicon[name];
    return IconComponent ? <IconComponent {...rest} /> : null;
};
```

and use it

```
<Icon name="Visibility" />
<Icon name="VisibilityOff" />
...
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ljn6c?file=/demo.js:191-220)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below

```
const SelectedIcon = Muicon[userIcon];

<SelectedIcon />
```